# updating user phoneNumber using firebase admin sdk is not working somehow

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to update user phone number used for authentication, I m using firebase admin sdk to update phone number of user, but it doesn't seems to work for me and I m not getting what m doing wrong-

As per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) for managing users, I m using below code in cloud function-

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import express = require("express");
import bodyParser = require("body-parser");
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./ServiceAccountKey.json");


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://projectname.firebaseio.com"
});

const db = admin.firestore();


const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
db.settings(settings);

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

/* Change user Mobile Number Request */
app.post("/mchangereq", (req, res) => {

  return admin
    .auth()
    .updateUser(req.body.uid, {
      phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
      emailVerified:Boolean(req.body.emailVerified)

    })
    .then((s) => {

      res.status(201).json({ message: "mobile number status", data:{...s} });
    }).catch(e => res.status(400).json({ err: e }));

});

exports.apphost = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

the code seems to be working, but it is not updating phoneNumber, I have tried updating other values like `emailVerified` that got udpated successfully, but phoneNumber is not updating.

Testing using Postman Snap- Output:[image: Postman POST request result]

Please let me know if any further info is needed on this query,
if there is any other method for updating phoneNumber, than a link to a doc will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()` after you update the user's phone number via the Firebase Admin SDK.
You may also want to call `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)` to force token refresh to contain the update phone number too.

Comment: @bojeli Thanks I will try this, but I have checked in firebase the mobile number for given uid is not changing

Comment: @bojeli what method is .currentuser it is not getting recognized, I m using firestore

Comment: Oops, it should be `currentUser`.

Comment: @bojeli have checked twice `auth()` method, it doesn't include any sub-method with name `currentUser`, it will be better if you can share some link or working sample code :)

Comment: @bojeli, I think you are referring this method at client side and I m searching this on adminSDK,  I think you want me to refer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential))

Comment: The answer is clear. After you updateUser via admin SDK, the changes take time to propagate on the client. The description I show above shows how to reload the user on the client to detect the new phone number.

Comment: I got your point, it was taking some fraction of time to reflect, API code was correct